# "Закладывать за воротник" — происхождение поговорки

Tags: фразеология

Интересно было бы узнать, откуда пошло выражение в отношении к питью спиртного "закладывать за воротник". Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не могу найти убедительный источник, поэтому - своими словами.

При Петре существовала практика клеймления подневольных работников на верфях и т.п. 
Клеймлению подвергались наиболее ценные мастеровые, чтобы не сбежали на другие работы. Клеймо ставилось на левую ключицу. Поимо основной функции это клеймо выполняло роль VIР-пропуска во все питеные заведения. Клеймленых поить обязаны были бесплатно. Когда наступал "час расплаты", посетитель просто расстегивал воротник - и к неудовольствию содержателя кабака щелкал себя по клейму (или чуть выше - по шее и подбородку). Жест этот тоже хорошо известен поныне.

Comment: Если нет убедительного источника, то это банальная байка. Про Петра да про 'Катьку-немку' таких много насочиняли. В словаре Даля это выражение не упоминается. Заложить за галстук, заложить за воротник, принять на грудь - фразеологизмы не очень давнишние. Про петровские клейма - полный бред...

Comment: А я вам не нанялся источники искать.

Comment: Не рассказывайте глупые басни. Сами-то большой любитель одернуть фантазеров, все требуете научных подходов, общепризнанных научных сведений))) Ссылок нет на клейма, но вы басню за ответ выдаете. Народной этимологией балуетесь? Несолидно, не по статусу чушь распространять)))  Минус за ответ.

Comment: А вот обсуждать с вами ничего не собираюсь.

Источники, ктсати, есть, другое дело, что акценты не так расставлены. 
http://mnogodetnaya-semya.ru/Semaya%20Kurbatovix/Semya%20Kurbatovix/O%20russkix%2021.html

Comment: Бред сивой кобылы, а не источники. В сети таких "источников" - эшелоны)))

Comment: По Сеньке и шапка. Понимаете, чтобы серьезно относиться к вашему "полный бред", надо иметь хоть какое-то для того основание. А вы ничего кроме "не очень давнишние" и ссылок на отсутствие чего-то там у Даля (ссылка на которого - само по себе уже нонсенс) не сообщаете.

Comment: Сотрите свой ответ, ОК?!

Comment: С какой стати?

Answer (score 4):

**Заложить за галстук** или **заложить за воротник**

""ЗАЛОЖИТЬ ЗА ГАЛСТУК И ПОДШОФЕ

Смешанное двуязычие, господствовавшее в речевом обиходе русского европеизированного дворянства с середины XVIII в., отразилось во многих разговорных выражениях, доживших до современности.

Шутливое выражение заложить за галстук, реже пропустить за галстук в значении `выпить хмельного, быть навеселе' в современном разговорном языке применяется не очень часто. По-видимому, оно уже начинает выходить из употребления, становится менее распространенным. Характерно, что иногда оно несколько деформируется: в устной фамильярной речи говорят и залить за галстук, а в вульгарном стиле — даже трахнуть за галстук. Эта группа выражений еще жива и понятна. В словаре Ушакова заложить или залить за галстук относится к живой фразеологии разговорно-шутливого стиля. У А. П. Чехова в рассказе «Певчие» воспроизведен такой разговор: «На что у тебя голос похож? Трещит словно кастрюля... опять, небось, вчерась, трахнул за галстук? Так и есть! изо рта, как из кабака...».

Выражению заложить за галстук около полутораста лет. Как показывает слово галстук, выражение это вышло из речи привилегированных классов; образ — заложить — косвенно намекает на военную среду, как место его широкого распространения (ср. заложить заряд, мину и т. п.). Есть свидетельство П. А. Вяземского о времени зарождения этого выражения и об его изобретателе. П. А. Вяземский в «Старой записной книжке» рассказывает о любимце брата императора Николая — великого князя Михаила Павловича — остряке, гвардейском полковнике Раевском: «Он был краснобай и балагур; был в некотором отношении лингвист, по крайней мере обогатил гвардейский язык многими новыми словами и выражениями, которые долго были в ходу и в общем употреблении, например: пропустить за галстук, немного подшефе (chauffé), фрамбуаз (framboise — малиновый) и пр. Все это по словотолкованию его значило, что человек лишнее выпил, подгулял» (Вяземский 1883, 3, с. 139—140).

Два выражения, созданные в начале XIX в. этим своеобразным лингвистом, из военно-офицерского диалекта надолго вошли в общелитературную разговорную речь. Это — пропустить или заложить за галстук и подшофе (также подшефе, под шефе).""

[В.В.Виноградов 'История слов'](http://wordhist.narod.ru/zalogit.html)

Статья В.В.Виноградова, представленная в моем ответе, камня на камне не оставляет от маргинальной версии про петровские клейма. Но на просторах инета басня о кабаках и мастеровых-пропойцах живуча, ведь якобы "сам" Петр Первый велел клеймить умельцев. Находятся легковерные простачки и распространяют подобную глупость...